# Unix - cannot assign list to array member

Tags: shell, unix

I am new to Unix programming and I am trying to store return values from list of directories into an array using `ls -ltr`. My shell code is here:

```
 cmd=("ls -ltr | grep ^- | awk  'NR==1{print NR":" $9}' | tr ' ' '\n'")
 file[$i]=(`echo eval $cmd`); //line no. 14
 echo ${file[$i]};
```

Now, here is the error message:

```
./file.sh: line 14: file[$i]: cannot assign list to array member
```

can anyone tell me what to do ?

Comment: I don't think that you can have array elements that are themselves arrays.  Also, as a general rule, avoid parsing the output of `ls`.  If you're sure you don't have spaces, newlines or other oddball characters in the file names, you may be OK, but it is very easy to get your script confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ ary=(*/)
$ printf "%s\n" "${ary[@]}"
```

#### Test:

```
$ touch file1 file2 file3
$ mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3
$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 test test 4096 Jul 26 06:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 test test 4096 Jul 26 06:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 test test 4096 Jul 26 06:05 dir1
drwxr-xr-x  2 test test 4096 Jul 26 06:05 dir2
drwxr-xr-x  2 test test 4096 Jul 26 06:05 dir3
-rw-r--r--  1 test test    0 Jul 26 06:05 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 test test    0 Jul 26 06:05 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 test test    0 Jul 26 06:05 file3
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ ary=(*/)
$ printf "%s\n" "${ary[@]}"
dir1/
dir2/
dir3/
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more robust to not rely on global flags. They influence the rest of your Code too.
You also shouldn't parse the output of an ls.
'ls' output depend on 'locale' settings and may differ.

Use 'find' to pick the files you want

```
myDir="."

find  $myDir  -maxdepth 1  -type f  -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | head -n 1
```

returns the oldest one in the directory.

(maxdepth restricts to the current directory and excludes the subdirs
-type f means Files only no dirs
-printf %T %p shows modification time followed by filename
)

Use

```
find  $myDir  -maxdepth 1  -type f  -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | head -n 1 | awk '{$1=""; print $0;}'
```

to get only the name of the file.